# Am I declaring partially specialized friend class? - very confused

Tags: c++, templates

I've been twiddling my thumbs over this one for far too much time now. I am trying to implement a single linked list using two different allocators for both the nodes and the type to which they point. The following code keeps complaining at me that I am partially specializing the friend class declaration within the SingleListNode definition:

```
namespace containers {
template<typename T, typename TAlloc,
typename NAlloc>class SingleList; // forward declaration

template<typename T, typename TAlloc = std::allocator<T>>
class SingleListNode {
    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    friend class SingleList<T1, T2, T3> ; // partially specialized???
    // class definition
};

template<typename T, typename TAlloc = std::allocator<T>,
        typename NAlloc = std::allocator<SingleListNode<T>>>
class SingleList {
    // class definition
};
} // end of namespace containers
```

Keeps telling me:

> ../src/singlelist.h:21:16: error: specialization of ‘template struct containers::SingleList’ must appear at namespace scope
>   ../src/singlelist.h:21:39: error: partial specialization ‘containers::SingleList’ declared ‘friend’

So far as I can tell, this isn't a specialization. Perhaps it is a bug in the GCC compiler? Otherwise, where am I going wrong?

Comment: out of curiosity why does a node need to know about the list it's part of?

Comment: @Nim: Why do you think it does? The `friend` declaration gives the list access to the nodes, not the other way round.

Comment: I would point out that generally the "data" is kept in the node by copy, and not by pointer, because this is more efficient storage-wise and plays better with cache (well, as efficient as a linked-list can be...); this is `std::list` behavior. Is there a specific reason you want to separate the allocation of the nodes from the allocation of the data itself ?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, doh, stupid comment without looking at the code properly, anyways, seems like that would allow any list type to access a particular node type's internals(?)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I need more practice with containers etc. Figured the best way would be to build them myself, hitting doors on the way down. Makes for a good mini project building a container class using two allocators. It may come in handy one day. Probably not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are *declaring* a templated friend class, so the correct syntax is

```
 template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> 
 friend class SingleList;
```

without the `<T1, T2, T3>` after `SingleList`.
See, for instance, the "practical usage example" [here](http://warp.povusers.org/programming/template_declarations.html)

Comment: @IanHaggerty: indeed :x I tested on Clang expecting better but the text is the same, bad luck :p